# Node js Promises with recursive function

Tags: node.js, recursion, promise

I want to read the all (text) files from a specific directory and it's all subdirecoty recursively.. I am able to read the file and append the result to a global variable. but i want to access the variable at the end of all operation. I am trying with promises but i am unable to access it. please help

```js
var file_path = `C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\test_folder`;
const fs = require('fs');
var final_array = [];

let getFolderTree = function(file_path) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    fs.readdir(file_path, function(err, folders) {
      if (err) {

        console.log("error reading folder :: " + err);

      } else {

        if (folders.length !== 0) {

          for (let i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {

            if (folders[i].endsWith("txt")) {

              let text_file_path = file_path + `\\` + folders[i];
   
              fs.readFile(text_file_path, function(error_read, data) {
                if (error_read) {
                  console.log("error reading " + error_read);
                } else {
                  
                  return resolve(final_array.push(data));// want to access final_array at the end of all operations
                }
              });
              
            } else {
              let current_path = file_path + `\\` + folders[i];
              getFolderTree(current_path);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
getFolderTree(file_path).then(function() {
  console.log(final_array); // this is not working 
});
```

Comment: If I'm understanding what your question is, you want to add `then` and `catch` to your recursive call: `getFolderTree(current_path).then(/*do something*/).catch(/*handle error*/);`  Also, if I'm reading your code right, your `for` loop isn't going to do what you're hoping.  And you're going to want to make sure your promise resolves/rejects in every case.

Answer (score 0):

I think i have found the solution but I am still confused about how it works.

I took reference from another code and able to figure out some how.

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
let root_path = "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\test_folder";

function getAllDirectoriesPath(current_path) {
    var results = [];
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        fs.readdir(current_path, function (erro, sub_dirs) {
            if (erro) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                let no_of_subdir = sub_dirs.length;
                if (!no_of_subdir) {
                    return resolve(results);
                } else {
                    sub_dirs.forEach(function (dir) {
                        dir = path.resolve(current_path, dir);
                        fs.stat(dir, function (err, stat) {
                            if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) {
                                getAllDirectoriesPath(dir).then(function (res) {
                                    results = results.concat(res);
                                    if (!--no_of_subdir) {
                                        resolve(results);
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                fs.readFile(dir, function (err, data) {
                                    results.push(data.toString());
                                    if (!--no_of_subdir) {
                                        resolve(results);
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
}

getAllDirectoriesPath(root_path).then(function (results) {
    console.log(results);
});
```